# Referencing a number inside a tuple

Tags: python-3.x, types

I want to arrange a list of tuples similar to the one bellow in descending order using the numbers:

> data = [('ralph picked', ['nose', '4', 'apple', '30', 'winner', '3']),
>   ('aaron popped', ['soda', '1', 'popcorn', '6', 'pill', '4',
>   'question', '29'])]

I would like to sort the nested list so that the outcome would look somewhat like:

```
data2 = [('ralph picked', ['apple', '30', 'nose', '4', 'winner', '3']), 
('aaron popped', ['question', '29', 'popcorn', '6', 'pill', '4', 'soda', '1'])]
```

I am trying to use this code for this:

```
data2=[]
for k, v in data:
    data2 = ((k,   sorted(zip(data[::2], data[1::2]), key=lambda x: int(x[1]), reverse=True)  ))
    [value for pair in data2 for value in pair]
print(data2)
```

But I keep getting the error message:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'tuple'
```

I tried to rearrange the `int` in `key=lambda x: int(x[1])` to different things, but I kept getting the same message, I am very new to python, the syntax often gets me. Any ideas on how to solve this? I really thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than trying to do everything at once, let's give things names:

```
data = [('ralph picked', ['nose', '4', 'apple', '30', 'winner', '3']),
        ('aaron popped', ['soda', '1', 'popcorn', '6', 'pill', '4', 'question', '29'])]

data2 = []
for k, v in data:
    new_list = sorted(zip(v[::2], v[1::2]), key=lambda x: int(x[1]), reverse=True)
    flattened = [value for pair in new_list for value in pair]
    new_tuple = (k, flattened)
    data2.append(new_tuple)
```

produces

```
>>> print(data2)
[('ralph picked', ['apple', '30', 'nose', '4', 'winner', '3']), 
 ('aaron popped', ['question', '29', 'popcorn', '6', 'pill', '4', 'soda', '1'])]
```

You need to distinguish between `data` and `v` -- you only want to sort `v`, and you need to store the result of the list comprehension, otherwise you're just building it and throwing it away.

When you're having trouble with the syntax, break everything apart into its pieces and `print` them to see what's going on.  For example, you could decompose `new_list` into

```
words = v[::2]
numbers = v[1::2]
pairs = zip(words, numbers)
sorted_pairs = sorted(pairs, key=lambda x: int(x[1]), reverse=True)
```

and `sorted_pairs` is really what `new_list` is.